# BASH: echo: write error: Invalid argument when settings power profiles for power_dpm_force_performance_level

Tags: bash, performance, amd-graphics, amdgpu-pro

```
root@valtok-msi:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# echo "manual" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

And if I try it without `sudo su` it gives me:

```
valtok@valtok-msi:~$ sudo echo "manual" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
bash: /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level: Permission denied
```

I really don't know what to do, I've been searching everywhere for this problem but seems like I'm the single one having it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to answer these: Which version of Ubuntu? What is the output of `uname -a` and `lsmod | grep -i amd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo puting new line at the end that could be the reason behind the error, So once try this:

```
echo -n "manual" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
```

Comment: YOOO HOLY SHIT IT WORKS THANK YOU SOO MUCH